# AngularJS post to Jersey generates com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator$8 resolve SEVERE: null

Tags: json, angularjs, http, post, jersey

I have a jersey server. When I attempt to handle a POST from AngularJS (1.2.16), it is generating an error (below).   When I use a java jersey client to post the message, the jersey server handles it fine.

SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator$8 can not access a member of class javax.ws.rs.core.Response with modifiers "protected"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:101)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)

this is the jersey post server:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/post")
public Response verifyAccount( Owner owner ,
    @Context HttpServletRequest req)
{
    LOGGER.debug("verify account " +owner.toString() );
    HashMap<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    boolean verified = AccountManagement.verifyAccount(owner.getEmail(),
        owner.getPwd());
    if (verified) {
        results.put("status", "OK");
    } else {
        results.put("status", "Fail");
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(results)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
        .build();
}
```

This is the jersey java client:

```
public class JsonClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("http://myserver.com:8080/restws/accountcheck/post");

        String input = "{\"email\":\"fubar@gmail.com\",\"pwd\":\"hello\"}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
            .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        int code = response.getStatus();
        if (code != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception caught.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is the AngularJS code to post:
    $scope.ownerLoginAction = function() {

```
var dataObject = {
"email": $scope.myId,
"pwd": $scope.mypassword
};

var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: hostName+'/restws/accountcheck/post',
        params: {
            action:"verify"
        },
        data: dataObject
    });
request.then (function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
   },function(errResponse) {
        console.error('Error');
    } )
}
```

Anybody know why I cannot seem to post either with JSON from AngularJS?   Is the server not set up right?  Or the angularJS client is not right?

When i put a TCPMON in between, I noticed that the angularJS attempt sent an OPTION.   Is that a clue that I dont understand?

Comment: Probably the error message will have to do with the class Owner. How do you define that class, is it yours?

Comment: Yes, Owner.java is mine.  It is define as a simple POJO:    @XmlRootElement public class Owner {   private String email;  private String pwd; }

Comment: @XmlRootElement 
 public class Owner {   
  private String email;  
  private String pwd;   
  public String getEmail() { return email;}
  
  public void setEmail(String e) {email = e;}
  public String getPwd() {return pwd;}
  public void setPwd(String e) {pwd = e;}
 }

Comment: I don't use Angular and I havent seen the excepcion you have, but you are probably missing a constructor without arguments in your class (for instronspection mechanism). Pls try it and let me know. Btw you should pass user/password using http headers. Hope it helps

Comment: I just added the default constructor for Owner, and put a logger debug statement -- and I noticed that it does get called.  But that did not resolve the original problem.

Comment: I tried to use JQuery, and I got the same or similar results.   I saw in the Chrome developer console this:   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/restws/wish/accountcheck/post?action=verify. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. manageaccount.html:1
Error while logging in as owner.   This is while I am using WebStorm to view my page and trying to debug.    I tried to add the headers into the request.  As you see, I already have those headers from the jersey response.

Comment: Resolved: I found that the CORS filter was not active with the jersey based java servlet.  I also found a better solution with springframework based RESTController.